# Java android app crashes on outputstream

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, outputstream

Here's my code where the app is crashing:

```
sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            try {
                mmOutputStream.write('f');
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

void openBT() throws IOException
{
    UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"); //Standard SerialPortService ID
    mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);        
    mmSocket.connect();
    mmOutputStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
    mmInputStream = mmSocket.getInputStream();

    beginListenForData();

    myLabel.setText("Bluetooth Opened");
}
```

Here's the error:

> 08-06 17:33:35.532: E/AndroidRuntime(17986): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   08-06 17:33:35.532: E/AndroidRuntime(17986): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   08-06 17:33:35.532: E/AndroidRuntime(17986):    at com.kiko.vozenjerc.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:93)
>   08-06 17:33:35.532: E/AndroidRuntime(17986):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java)
>   08-06 17:33:35.532: E/AndroidRuntime(17986):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java)
>   08-06 17:33:35.532: E/AndroidRuntime(17986):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java)
>   08-06 17:33:35.532: E/AndroidRuntime(17986):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
>   08-06 17:33:35.532: E/AndroidRuntime(17986):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
>   08-06 17:33:35.532: E/AndroidRuntime(17986):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
>   08-06 17:33:35.532: E/AndroidRuntime(17986):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   08-06 17:33:35.532: E/AndroidRuntime(17986):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   08-06 17:33:35.532: E/AndroidRuntime(17986):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
>   08-06 17:33:35.532: E/AndroidRuntime(17986):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
>   08-06 17:33:35.532: E/AndroidRuntime(17986):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Can you provide more code ?Right now I guess `mmOutputStream` is null

Comment: I've edited the first post and added more code... I don't know what part of the code would be useful to you.. But I guess this is that part.